# running a make command for John the Ripper in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

I am a newbie to Linux and ubuntu, but i am trying to install John the Ripper on a new server running ubuntu 15.04. i have it downloaded using:

```
wget http://www.openwall.com/john/j/john-1.8.0.tar.xz
```

then i unpacked it with:

```
tar -xzvf john-1.8.0.tar.gz
```

then, i cd into the src directory as per the instructions and run:

```
sudo make clean linux-x86-64
```

and this error is being returned (and i am trying to figure out what it means/ how to fix it)

```
rm -f ../run/john ../run/unshadow ../run/unafs ../run/unique
../run/john.bin ../run/john.com ../run/unshadow.com ../run/unafs.com 
../run/unique.com ../run/john.exe ../run/unshadow.exe ../run/unafs.exe 
../run/unique.exe
rm -f ../run/john.exe john-macosx-* *.o *.bak core
rm -f detect bench generic.h arch.h tmp.s
cp /dev/null Makefile.dep
ln -sf x86-64.h arch.h
make ../run/john ../run/unshadow ../run/unafs ../run/unique \
JOHN_OBJS="DES_fmt.o DES_std.o DES_bs.o DES_bs_b.o BSDI_fmt.o MD5_fmt.o 
MD5_std.o BF_fmt.o BF_std.o AFS_fmt.o LM_fmt.o trip_fmt.o dummy.o  
batch.o bench.o charset.o common.o compiler.o config.o cracker.o 
crc32.o external.o formats.o getopt.o idle.o inc.o john.o list.o 
loader.o logger.o math.o memory.o misc.o options.o params.o path.o 
recovery.o rpp.o rules.o signals.o single.o status.o tty.o wordlist.o 
unshadow.o unafs.o unique.o c3_fmt.o x86-64.o" \
CFLAGS="-c -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer  
-DHAVE_CRYPT" \
LDFLAGS="-s  -lcrypt"
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mike/john-1.8.0/src'
gcc -c -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer  -  
DHAVE_CRYPT -funroll-loops DES_fmt.c
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
Makefile:896: recipe for target 'DES_fmt.o' failed
make[1]: *** [DES_fmt.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/john-1.8.0/src'
Makefile:183: recipe for target 'linux-x86-64' failed
make: *** [linux-x86-64] Error 2
```

Comment: There should be no need to compile under `sudo`. In fact, it's probably a bad idea. When you want to do a system-wide install, then you'll need `sudo make install`.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't simply install the [official package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/john)?

Comment: there are a couple reasons @tripleee, first and most important is the fact that it costs money (not worth the cost for one project). and second, there is a bit of customization that can be done prior to the install that allows for a much faster process.

Comment: Huh?  No, installing a Debian package does not cost money.

Comment: from the JTR website, you can purchase the pro edition which is compiled, or download the non compiled version for free. thats all i know about.

Comment: There is a Debian package (of the free download, I presume) so you don't need to compile it yourself. Clicking the link in my second comment would have revealed its precise name, version, and download locations; but I assume you can simply `aptitude install john` in Ubuntu, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the C compiler, GCC.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

You will probably bump into missing libraries next. Read the documentation in the tarball to find out what else you need. (Probably at least `libcrypt-dev`.)